# memory access violations and windows

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault

So I am working on the exercise below, and I understand the problems related to dereferencing  null pointer as in the code below.
Swap.c

```
int main () {
int a = 1, b = 2;
swap(&a, &b);
}

void swap (int *px, int *py) {
int *temp;
*temp = *px; //Crashes here
*px = *py;
*py = *temp;
}
```

Now my issues is on my pc I always get sigsegv if proc exists or not. I assume this is windows not allowing memory access violations.This makes it impossible to really do the exercise below. Does this behave differently on a native Linux machine? Suggestions?

(Exercise) Create swap.c
Supply the definition of a C procedure proc to be called in the main
program immediately prior to the call to the buggy swap (swap2.s) that
will guarantee that swap will crash when the uninitialized temp pointer is
dereferenced (it should cause a crash on *temp). Also explain why your
call guarantees this crash. Hint: your proc procedure will leave
something on the stack.

```
int main () {
int a = 1, b = 2;
proc(/* Some args might go here */);
swap(&a, &b);
}
```

Q2. Explain how you guarantee it crashing with what is in proc.

But this is tricky when it always crashes at the deref.?

Comment: well if it always crashes, reverse the exercise and make it not crash.  Then if you are able to make it never crash you can modify it to _always_ crash.

Comment: It already always crashes, making not crash will not help with proc, please read the exercise. The goal is to without modifying swap provide a function that executes before swap which leaves something on the stack. My point is experimenting to do this seem impossible when it already always crashes. and fixing the bug to make it not crash is not allowed.

Comment: (Exercise) Create swap.c Supply the definition of a C procedure proc to be called in the main program immediately prior to the call to the buggy swap (swap2.s) that will guarantee that swap will crash when the uninitialized temp pointer is dereferenced (it should cause a crash on *temp). Also explain why your call guarantees this crash. Hint: your proc procedure will leave something on the stack.

Comment: I mean -- make it not crash w/o fixing the bug.  Make it not crash by placing a valid address on stack.